# Problem in getting data in dropdown in Angular

Tags: angular, api, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate a dropdown from a `get` API. I've created a service and using the observables returning the data to the component, which then subscribes to the service. I'm able to get the data but it it reflects in Drop down only when i click once anywhere outside the dropdown menu. The data comes instantly in `console.log` when the page refresh but the dropdown gets data only when I click somewhere outside the dropdown. I have tried reading many posts regarding the dropdown but could not resolve this issue. My code is below, the behavior remains same if i remove the clause `(change)=selectedHandlerProjectId($event)`:

**sample.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>
   <h3>Select ProjectName</h3>
 </label>
 <select (change)=selectedHandlerProjectId($event) ngModel="selectedProjectName" class="form-control">
     <option *ngFor="let Project of ProjectDetails" >{{Project.ProjectName}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

**sample.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class sampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public ProjectDetails: TestProject[] = []; 

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private projService:projectService) { }

    getSelectedProject(): void{  
      this.projService.generateProjectList().subscribe(
        projectDetails => {
          this.projectDetails = projectDetails;
          console.log(this.projectDetails);
        }  
      );
    }


  //methods to get dropdown values
  dropDownProjectId: string = '';
  selectedHandlerProjectId(event : any)
  {
    if(event.target.value != 'default') { 
      this.dropDownProjectId = event.target.value;}
    else {this.dropDownProjectId = null;}
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSelectedProject();
  }
```

**sample.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceConstants} from "../../shared/service-constants";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {TestProject} from "../models/model.component";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class projectService {

  rootUrl: string = `${ServiceConstants.project_URL}/test-project-manager`;

  constructor(private authHttp: HttpClient) {
  }

  generateProjectList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.authHttp.get<Array<TestProject>>(`${this.rootUrl}/testprojects`);  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`
Angular needs to be informed of when you have updated a field on the class.

So when you are setting `this.projectDetails = projectDetails;` angular doesn't know that projectDetails now contains your data.

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private projService:projectService) { }

    getSelectedProject(): void{  
      this.projService.generateProjectList().subscribe(
        projectDetails => {
          this.projectDetails = projectDetails;
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          console.log(this.projectDetails);
        }  
      );
    }
```

To make angular detect your change to the component you import the `ChangeDetectorRef` and call detectChanges() on it.

Comment: Thanks Leon. It also resolved my another issue wherein the data was getting displayed after pressing the submit button twice.
My ultimate aim is to select a project name from the drop down menu and then show that project details by fetching the details from another api passing the selected projectname as an argument. I am facing 1 more issues here:

If i have only one project in the database, the value is not getting selected from the drop down menu. This works fine if i have more than 1 projects in the database. in component.ts console.log(this.selectedProjectName) is displaying undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Remove that line and everything will be working or

Change

```
 public ProjectDetails: TestProject[] = [];
```

TO

```
public ProjectDetails: Array<TestProject>;
```

Means without any default value;

Or

```
this.projectDetails = projectDetails;
this.projectDetails = this.projectDetails.slice();
```

This way `this.projectDetails` refers a different array instance and Angular will recognize the change.

Comment: Thanks Ali for answering but i already tried removing the changeDetection and it didnot worked however  it did worked after implementing cdr: ChangeDetectorRef.